# Using Jquery .each() function to hide images as another image is shown in the same class

Tags: jquery

I am using the stellar.js to make a paralax site. I have images of feet set up to show at different points during scrolling. I am trying to write a function that will hide all other copies of the feet when one is shown. I can't change the stellar file itself to do this so I have to try and use an outside function:

```
//Feet on slide
$('.walkingFoot').each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        $('.walkingFoot').not(this).css('display','none');
    }   
});
```

All of the feet images in the set are in the .walkingFoot class. What I am trying to do is hide all other feet in the class when the display property is set to block. The code above does not seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So only one element with that class is set to `display:block` at a time? What are the rest set to?

Comment: The rest are set to display:none basically I am trying to find a way to hide each individual foot image after the new image triggers and is set to display:block

Comment: How are you deciding that a new .walkingFoot should be displayed? Your code, as it is here, will always just find the first one that is display: block, and then set the others to display: none.

Comment: how is your code implemented with stellar.js?

Comment: Ok, the stellar.js file is defining when new .walkingFoot items are displayed. Due to restrictions I am not allowed to change anything within the stellar.js file. @koala_dev this code is in a separate file and I was hoping to just be able to use it to continue to effect the items effected by stellar.

Comment: Your code is only going to run once... is there a callback function that is available once the change is made by stellar.js?  You would need to listen, somehow, for the change to be made, then run the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code in:

```
$('.walkingFoot').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        $('.walkingFoot').not(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2NEPY/